# How does it possible that Ubuntu image has only ~100MB?

Tags: docker

I can't understand one thing. I read about images and AUFS file system and I think that I got it. However, when I look at iso file on ubuntu site it is meaningfully more than `100MB`. Where is key ? In graphical enviroment? (eg. KDE)

Comment: The _base_ image does not contain KDE.  There are (approximately) 25k packages in Ubuntu.  Not all of those are in the _base_ container which is meant to just that: a _base_ to build from.

Comment: Ok, So it minimal version of ubuntu ? Kernel + some tools + some drivers ?. Then, launching  `apt-get` may download very much dependencies, yeah ?

Comment: Docker images don't need a kernel.

Comment: Yes, I know it now. so some drivers and some tools eg. `ls` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker Images are **minimal** meaning, they contain only a few number of libraries (needed libraries). They don't include kernel, because containers use docker host's kernel.

You can download and inspect official ubuntu cloud image (source of library/ubuntu yekkety) from [here](https://partner-images.canonical.com/core/yakkety/current/).

Another thing to note: Base images usually don't include window managers and desktop environments.

Comment: thanks for you clear answer. *because containers use docker host's kernel.* Do you mean currently running kernel ? (For example my host computer has at this momemen five kernels). And second thing: This image is `cloud image` ?